# Where clause in MapInfo Table Updates

Tags: sql, mapinfo, update

Is it possible to add a where condition to an update query in MapInfo?

At the moment I have to do a query to select the records I need and then do an update on that query.

I believe this is possible with SQL so I wanted to know whether it could be done in MapInfo.

Answer (score 2):

You can do "update .... where rowid = N", but that is all. A single specific record or the whole table/selection.